# creating/appending html elements (browser memory)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, memory

When I `appendChild()` to `dom[0]` you would think that it moves `dom[1]` and `dom[2]` but instead it actually duplicates/copies the elements underneath `dom[0]`, since they still remain elements of actual `dom` array.

//JS

```
var dom = [];
var element = new Array("div","p","h1");
for(var i=0; i < element.length; i++){
    dom.push(document.createElement(element[i]))
}
dom[0].appendChild(dom[1]);
dom[0].appendChild(dom[2]);
console.log(dom); //div,p,h1
console.log(dom[0].children);//p,h1
console.log(dom.length); //3
```

**Question:** When if ever, does the element(s) get removed from memory?

Comment: There is no copying.... array contains **references** to dom objects

Comment: You can use the array method `.shift()` to move objects into the first place of the array.

Comment: Objects get removed from memory by the garbage collector when there's no way to access them from any variables or DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question arises from a very false assumption:

The array `dom` does NOT mirror the actual `DOM` structure.

You are creating three elements and you are assigning a *reference* to those elements into your array.

You are also assigning a *reference* to those elements in the `DOM` itself.

So, each element ends up with two references that point to it -- the `dom` array and the `DOM` itself.

The references are *completely* independent from the elements themselves.  You could create a half-dozen local variables that all point to the same elements.

The elements will be freed when:

- Nothing is still referring to them

  - That includes `dom`
  - And the `DOM`
  - and any local variables
- The garbage collector runs.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. I know the `dom` array isn't the actual DOM but still didn't understand when they get removed... for clarification though, if I don't remove like you mentioned the `dom` array, they will remain in memory?

Comment: Correct, if you keep the values in the `dom` array, they will not be freed during the page's life cycle.  This is a common cause of memory leaks in JavaScript.  (ES6 supports a new feature called `WeakMaps` that kind-of-sort-of hold onto a value.  If they are the only thing holding onto a reference, they'll let it go.)

Comment: awesome you are the man! yea I'll read more into WeakMaps I've read a little about them a few months ago. Thanks for your help!